# Collection not loaded from settings when is initialised in class

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Using Net 6 I have the following Program.cs configuration:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
  .AddJsonFile($"settings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true)
  .AddEnvironmentVariables();

builder.Services.Configure<Options>(builder.Configuration);
```

And the Options class is:

```
public partial class Options {
  public IEnumerable<Application> Applications { get; set; } = new List<Application>();
}
```

On a Minimal Api Endpoint I have:

```
builder.MapPost("posts", async ([FromServices] IOptionsMonitor<Options> options, ...) => {
  
  var value = options.CurrentValue;

  var applications = value.Applications;

});
```

In this case `applications` is an empty collection.

If I don't initialise the `Applications` property in `Options` class, e.g.:

```
public partial class Options {
  public IEnumerable<Application> Applications { get; set; } = new List<Application>();
}
```

I am then able to get the applications inside the Api endpoint.

Isn't this behaviour strange? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ...

The property Applications must be a concrete type, e.g:

```
public partial class Options {
  public List<Application> Applications { get; set; } = new List<Application>();
}
```